# HOW I CAN MAKE TAB SCREE LIKE THAT IN FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

I want to make screen like that using flutter. The screen must have 2 tabs .both tab screens load on same main screen  Eg. when user click tab one on screen load tab one ( as the photo) and click Tab 2 on screen load tab 2. How I can do that code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PageView()` to show more than one page at the same place.

you need to pass to de `PageView()` the `controller` (which is a widget of `PageController`)

so you can call the `pageController.animateToPage()` so you can animate and switch between pages...

you can find how to use the `PageView` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A), they explain really well!

hope that helped!